# The uri on standalone fuse esb?

Tags: web-services, jbossfuse, apache-servicemix

My question is that my esb (fuse or servicemix) is running on standalone server and an application want to invoke a web service via esb.for this,i opened a queue for taking the webservice client.And for this the application want to learn the URI for invoking web service via esb.What should be the URI ?

Answer (score 0):

In the shell of JBoss Fuse you can type cxf:list-endpoints which list all the web service links.

The links are relative, so the url is `http://localhost:8181/cxf/` as prefix.

You can find more details in the JBoss Fuse docs at

- https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Fuse/